# DNS look up, hash tables

Tags: c++, data-structures, hash

Below image is the final homework in our data structures course.

The problem is to write a DNS lookup program that maps domains into their ip addresses using the registered domain name servers.

I have some ideas but I wonder if these are among the correct way of implementing this program.

I thought I could make use of a hash table for registering domain name servers. Then `registerDNS`, and `deleteDNS` methods would be **constant time**.

For registering URLs, again a hash table. But the thing bothering me here is they give a `vector<string> &dnsChain`, which provides information about how to go to the DNS that holds the URL.

Now `registerURL` and `deleteURL` are **constant time** too. But we are storing a vector in each cell of our hash table, which I believe increases **space complexity**.(What if you had a million URL, with a `dnsChain` with million elements in each cell?)

For the `access` method, I believe we should lookup in DNS hash table to make sure that every DNS in  `dnsChain` of that URL are registered. That makes accessing **O(N)**, if  you have N domain name servers in the `dnsChain`. Is this acceptable?

Also there is this merge method that merge two DNS. My idea is to use a vector in each cell of DNS hashtable. If we merge DNS2 to DNS1, then we can push DNS2 to the vector of DNS1, which implies DNS1 also contains DNS2.

May the space complexity be reduced? Do we have to store `dnsChain` in each cell of URL hashtable?

Do we have to traverse through each DNS in `dnsChain` to access a URL?(if 10^6 DNS to access a URL, wouldn't it be slow?)

Or is there any other helper data structure or technique(trie, extendible hashing, BST) I can use in this case?

[image: dns manager]

Comment: If it weren't so open-ended and broad this might have been a good Programmers.SE question.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework, I'll only give some very high level suggestions.

Considering that many of the dnsChains have repeated URLs, I'd suggest storing the dnsChains in a tree which would presumably save a tremendous amount of space if the Chains have a lot of repetition and are long. One thing to watch out for is that the trees will have to contain a count of how many times it has been added/deleted and should only be deleted if the count hits 0.

A neat data structure that could be used here to speed up the access function is a bloom filter. This is probabilistic but only gives false positives occasionally, but never false negatives. These are also used in industry to speed up caching. More information can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).

Comment: dnsChains have actually ip addresses, but I think I got it. If every URL is accessed with  the same dnsChain, then one tree node would suffice, instead of storing the same dnsChain for million times, right?

Comment: Yes, though you might need to be careful of how you delete/add the tree nodes.